# EI and APIm: Response payload is wrapped inside binary element

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ei

1.1  - API Manager 2.1.0
If I sent a POST  request through a simple mediation (pass through) when the binary relay was enabled, the response payload generated by ESB has been wrapped inside a binary element as follows..

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPAction
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 16 Jan 2018 14:53:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">DCAAAAApACkAAAJxdXVpZDo3MTRDNkM0MC00NT.......</ns:binary></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

In ESB 5.0.0 and API manager 2.0.0 all works well.

Comment: Which version of EI did you try this on?

Comment: i tried with version 6.1.1

Comment: I added th following line to axis2.xml:
<messageFormatter contentType="text/xml"              class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>

Comment: I added th following line to axis2.xml:
<messageFormatter contentType="text/xml"              class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>   
and the formatter worked expanding the binary field. It seems that the ContentType is wrongly set to "text/xml"